# Select FROM Subquery without starting with another context object

Tags: entity-framework-core, subquery, asp.net-core-webapi, maximo

I am trying to model the following MSSQL query that I am trying to replicate in netCore 2.2 - EF Core:

```
SELECT
wonum,
MIN(requestdate)        AS startdate,
MAX(requestdate)        AS enddate,
MIN(laborcode)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            wo.wonum,
            sw.requestdate,
            wo.wolablnk     AS 'laborcode'
        FROM
            DB1.dbo.web_users           wu  INNER JOIN
            DB2.dbo.workorder           wo on
            wu.laborcode = wo.wolablnk          INNER JOIN
            DB2.dbo.sw_specialrequest   sw  on
            wo.wonum = sw.wonum
    WHERE
            wo.status           in ('LAPPR', 'APPR', 'REC') AND
            sw.requestdate      > GETDATE()
    ) a   
GROUP BY
   wonum
ORDER by
```

I have the subquery portion built and working but that leaves me at an impasse:

```
        var workOrders = await _db1Context.Workorder
            .Where(r => r.Status == "LAPPR" || r.Status == "APPR" || r.Status == "REC")
            .ToListAsync();

        var specialRequests = await _db2Context.SwSpecialRequest
            .Where(r => r.Requestdate > DateTime.Now)
            .ToListAsync();

        var subQuery = (from webUser in webUsers
                        join workOrder in workOrders on webUser.Laborcode equals workOrder.Wolablnk
                        join specialRequest in specialRequests on workOrder.Wonum equals specialRequest.Wonum
                        orderby webUser.Laborcode, specialRequest.Requestdate, specialRequest.Wonum
                        select new { workOrder.Wonum, Laborcode = workOrder.Wolablnk, specialRequest.Requestdate, workOrder.Workorderid })
                        .ToList();
```

I am not sure how to initiate the query I need with the subquery i've built and i'm not sure if I am on the right track even. I've looked at a couple of other examples but i'm not getting it.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on the subject and help?

Thank you!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and create a proper class model first. With navigation properties, so you don't need manual joins and gain a lot of expressiveness. And show the class model.

Comment: Thank you and I agree about models! Sometimes I dont start with models when I am  learning, maybe I should have. It definitely would make for a more understandable help request for sure. Honestly, I hadn't thought about nav props at first and would love to use that approach. This is a microservice system with 3 separate dbs across 2 separate db servers - the tables are not all linked in 1 database or even server - it's probably possible to make a class with nav props to represent this, but i'm just not there yet. Thanks again, I will look into possibilities and build classes once i'm finished!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write LINQ query identical to the SQL and do not mix with `ToListAsync()`. After `ToListAsync()` query is sent to the server. Also you should use only one `DbContext` for such query.

```cs
var webUsers = _db1Context.Webuser;

var workOrders = _db1Context.Workorder
   .Where(r => r.Status == "LAPPR" || r.Status == "APPR" || r.Status == "REC");

var specialRequests = _db1Context.SwSpecialRequest
   .Where(r => r.Requestdate > DateTime.Now);

var subQuery = 
   from webUser in webUsers
   join workOrder in workOrders on webUser.Laborcode equals workOrder.Wolablnk
   join specialRequest in specialRequests on workOrder.Wonum equals specialRequest.Wonum
   select new 
   { 
       workOrder.Wonum, 
       Laborcode = workOrder.Wolablnk, 
       specialRequest.Requestdate
   };

var resultQuery = 
   from a in subQuery
   group a by a.Wonum into g
   select new 
   {
       Wonum = g.Key,
       StartDate = g.Min(x => x.Requestdate),
       EndDate = g.Max(x => x.Requestdate),
       Laborcode = g.Min(x => x. Laborcode)
   };

// final materialization
var result = await resultQuery.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you, working through this now. I have three separate databases i'm working with, one using code first one on database server and two using database first on a second database server. I am unsure about how I can or if I can have one context with this model, but will research it and appreciate the help -  the bit about when to use ToListAsync() was super 

Comment: @ogg130, You cannot create cross database queries using EF Core.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!